# android app crashes when trying to get txt file from webserver

Tags: android, text-files

my app crashes when trying to get a remote txt file.
even if just try to parse a url it crashes.
internet permission is set and the device/vm has connection to the internet.

LogCat:
[image]

code snippet:

```
try {
    // the following line is enough to crash the app
    URL url = new URL("http://www.i.am/not/going/to/show/you/this.txt");


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        //get lines
    }
    in.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i don't inderstand what i'm doing wrong. thanks for help in advance.

//edit: added log cat snippet

Comment: Anytime you get a crash, the important information is recorded in the LogCat. Please post your relevant logcat exceptions.

Comment: added link to log cat screenshot

Comment: @user1687295 Are you testing this application on which device API Version?

Comment: it's running on api level 10 (android 2.3.3)

Answer (score 1):

The application is crashing due to heavy network activity on the main UI thread, which itself is not a very good practice, as the application can stop responding and might get killed by the OS. You should always try to do your background processing in some separate thread, and not on the main UI thread.

Put your code to fetch the file inside the **`doInBackground()`** of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground() {
         try {

       URL url = new URL("http://www.i.am/not/going/to/show/you/this.txt");       

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        //get lines
    }
    in.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    //called when the background task makes any progress
 }

  protected void onPreExecute() {
     //called before doInBackground() is started
 }
 protected void onPostExecute() {
     //called after doInBackground() has finished 
 }
  }
```

You can make a call to this task to fetch the file by **`new DownloadFile().execute("");`** where ever you would you want to get the file.

Comment: It's not just a bad practice - under recent versions of Android (4+), it's explicitly forbidden. In fact, the telling exception `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is what the OP is facing. Android makes no distinction between heavy and light network usage. A mere attempt to call certain methods - such as `openStream()` over an HTTP URL - will give you an exception.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev : Oh, okay. Thanks for pointing it out sir. I haven't been working much on Android 4+ and hence was not aware of the issues. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: if i try to inizialize the object, the app does not crash anymore, thanks for this, i'll try tomorrow to access the text delivered by the downloadfile class.

Comment: seems like i don't know to access the text, i tried it with an static array, which i fetched after i executed the .execute("") method but it seems  to be empty. may i get some help on this?

Comment: Do not put the code to access the text after `.execute()`. It would be empty because you are calling it even before the AsyncTask finished downloading it. So, you need to write the corresponding code to get the text inside `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: okay this sounds good but now i set a boolean to true in the `onPostExecute()` method and i check it every second in my MainActivity class. in the emulator, the program doesn't do anything. the .txt file is very small (several KBs).

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "does not do anything" ?

Comment: Checking it every seconds is not a bad idea, but wont it be better if you called the code to access the file inside postExecute () ? The motive behind post execute that it gets called once the file finishes downloading, so that you do not have to keep on checking it continuously.